# JAVA Boolean.toString() override

Tags: java, boolean, tostring

I have method `printB()`:

```
private static final void printB () {
    System.out.println(Boolean.TRUE); 
    System.out.println(Boolean.FALSE);     
}
```

and I have class

```
public class ChangeBooleanValue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Add code
        printB();      
    }


    private static final void printB () {
        System.out.println(Boolean.TRUE);     
        System.out.println(Boolean.FALSE); 
    } 
}
```

I want to write code instread of `// Add Code` so that the output will be:

```
true 
true
```

or

```
false
false
```

I know that it is possible using by some Java tricks.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve. Is this a homework problem? Did you try anything?

Comment: Your title answers your question.

Comment: what is a "suck well"?

Comment: @pstanton you don't really want to know that ;)

Comment: @arshajii how many edits to a doomed question are you going to bother to make ;)

Comment: @pstanton Well I think this is an interesting question and worth making intelligible.

Comment: "interesting" like my 2 year old's drawings ;)

Comment: @hexafraction yes it's my homework

Comment: Are you allowed to use external libs?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
System.out.println(true);
System.out.println(true);
System.exit(0);
```

You can do the same thing with `false` as well.

---

The full code would look like this:

```
public class ChangeBooleanValue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(true);  // <--
        System.out.println(true);  // <--
        System.exit(0);            // <--
        printB();      
    }


    private static final void printB() {
        System.out.println(Boolean.TRUE);     
        System.out.println(Boolean.FALSE); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: or `System.out.println(!true);` ;)

Comment: Task is: "don't change code which is written. add but not change code which is written"

Comment: @G.Ch. This *doesn't* change anything which is already written, it is simply a substitute for the `Add code` comment (as you asked for).

Comment: this code is generating output like this :
true
false

I want to add code which will generate output where will be written two same values. not three , not one.

Comment: @G.Ch. Copy and paste this where you have written `Add code`; the output will be `true true` (on separate lines).

Comment: and when I invoke method it also generate output with two values

Comment: @G.Ch. I've added the full code, which satisfies the requirements you've detailed in your question. If there is something else that you have not mentioned, please add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflections to change `Boolean.TRUE = Boolean.FALSE` or visa-versa.  Not that there is a sane reason to do so.

Another way to do this is to compile your own version of Boolean class and use that to do whatever you want, again not at all sane.

Comment: It is not possible to assign a value to  final variable

Answer (score 1):

You use reflection to remove the final modifier and replace Boolean.FALSE with true.

Described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301720/131773

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class EverythingIsTrue {
   static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception {
      field.setAccessible(true);

      Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
      modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
      modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

      field.set(null, newValue);
   }
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {      
      setFinalStatic(Boolean.class.getField("FALSE"), true);

      System.out.format("Everything is %s", false); // "Everything is true"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code from [OliverS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18576709/2362664):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

public class ChangeBooleanValue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Add code
        try {
            Field f = Boolean.class.getField("FALSE");
            f.setAccessible(true);

            Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
            modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
            modifiersField.setInt(f, (f.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL));
            f.set(null, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        printB();
    }

    private static final void printB() {
        System.out.println(Boolean.TRUE);
        System.out.println(Boolean.FALSE);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
```